# Issue in setting inline style for element in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is the sample html to reproduce the issue.

```
<html>

   <head>
     <title>Title</title>
   </head>

<body> 
     <h1 id="head">Header1</h1> 
 </body> 
 <script>
   var element = document.getElementById("head");
   element.style.color = 'red';

  </script>


</html>
```

The styling works fine in firefox and in chrome; but not in IE.
All answers about this issue suggested the above method to make it work across browsers. But this simple sample doesn't work.

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/b4nd4z26/) in IE11? You should place your script in `head` or in `body` though.

Comment: Styling the `head` element - Is that a new thing?

Comment: @AlonEitan ya I have never seen this

Comment: @Alon and labago, they are styling `h1` ; ).

Comment: @AlonEitan he is styling `#head`, not the `<head>` tag. xD

Comment: You guys :P thanks :)

Comment: Can you double check that the element exists (#head) in the DOM before doing the query selector? `if (document.getElementById('head') !== null`)

Comment: @Teemu, Thanks for the clarification. It turns out, I had selected emulation of ie7 in document mode some time ago and totally forgot about it. I changed it back and it worked.

Comment: Placing a script outside of valid elements seems to be automatically fixed in FF and Chrome, as well as in IE11. Do you see any errors in the IE console?